Picker is underlined after being focused
AFAIK, the only way to programatically open a Picker is to call picker.Focus().  However, when you do that in Android, the component is underlined, and remains underlined until another component is interacted with.
Presumably this is the "focus" outline being incorrectly shown.  How can I prevent this outline from being shown?
Previous answers for Xamarin said to set picker.BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent, but that didn't work.

The only solution I've found is to add a native Handler to set the BackgroundTintList
// BUGFIX: Picker has an underline for some reason when being focused
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PickerHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(ITextStyle.Font), (handler, view) =>
{
    handler.PlatformView?.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
});

